# Computer keeps locking me out

Tags: windows-xp, login

When I'm away from my computer (Windows XP) for more than ~30 minutes, I get locked out, and have to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to login. I've checked the screensaver settings, and it's not set to lock the screen.

Does anyone know what else could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your computer may be going to 'sleep' or even 'hibernate'. Check your settings to ensure that the computer is not set to lock on sleep/hibernate or make it so the times are longer before this happens. You should be able to find the settings in your 'Power settings' from the Control Panel.